# how to get list of transactions history about specific contract address using web3?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, tokens, addresses, web3.py

I really don't know how to get a list of transactions history about specific contract address using web3.py

and I use Infura HTTPProvider

I just have only one 'contract address'.

Can i get information about this contract address using web3.py?

Comment: The question says `web3.py`. The tagging says `web3.js`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Getting all transaction history requires you to iterate over each and every block since the contract creation. As you might guess, this would be extremely slow, plus it depends on your `Infura` plan: rate limits and number of historical blocks available.

### Faster Solution without `web3py`

Instead, you can use indexing services, such as `Etherscan`.

As explained in [API docs](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts), you can then query for transaction history in the following way:

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page=1&offset=10&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

### Slower solution with `web3py`

If your Infura plan allows it, you can iterate over blocks and get block details using `eth_getBlockByNumber` JSON-RPC method. In `web3py`, it is equivalent to `web3.eth.getBlock(blocknumber)`. Then you would iterate over transaction hashes using `web3.eth.getTransaction(txhash)` and check for from/to address against your contract address. See:

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.getTransaction

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.getBlock

Comment: `account` is not contract. This gives you the list of transactions for an account, not the list of all transaction with a smart contract.